# Gson - how to serialize / deserialize a field, based on value of a different field?

Tags: java, gson

We have pretty large class:

```
class Foo {
    // ... many fields
    @Expose
    @JsonAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    Date start;

    @Expose
    String startTimeZone;
    // ... more fields
}
```

Now, locally, the values of start are stored as UTC, and the timezone info is stored separately in startTimeZone. However, when sending the data to the server, we need to **convert the start to the startTimeZone** and format it to a string "YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss".

We have this DateAdpater class

```
public class DateAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Date>, JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        return DateUtils.parseServerDateTime(json.getAsString);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(DateUtils.formatServerDateTime(src));
    }
}
```

However, in the DateAdapter we have no access to the startTimeZone field so we cannot use it for formatting/parsing.

I know that we could write a custom adapter for the whole class, but as said, the class is pretty large, so I'd rather have a different solution.

Comment: Maybe you could create a custom adapter for the whole class, call `context.serialize()` inside it to serialize everything else and handle `startTimeZone` differently?

Comment: @Pateman Thanks for the hint, I didn't know that is possible. Seems like the perfect solution. I will try on monday. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it, if it works out.

Comment: @Pateman Unfortunately your idea does not work. Calling context.serialize() inside serialize leads to an infinite loop and eventually a stack overflow. It would perhaps work with an artifical parent class but my class is a RealmObject and they don't allow inheritance :-/

Comment: So you can't create a class whose field is a reference to the class that you're trying to serialize? Something like `class Foo { private <your_class> instance; }` ?

Comment: @Pateman You mean like a wrapper? That would perhaps work, but then I'd have to change all the code to not use the class, but the wrapper ... like instead of foo.getStart() it would have to be wrapper.getFoo().getStart()...

Comment: I'm not sure how your code is structured, but the wrapper class could possibly be used only inside the class responsible for serialization. Like this: `public JsonElement serialize(Foo foo) { Wrapper w = new Wrapper(foo); Gson gson = new Gson(); JsonElement wrapped = gson.toJsonTree(w); return ((JsonObject) wrapped).get("foo");}`

Comment: But then we're back to the infinite loop again, because when serializing Wrapper, it will again serialize the Foo field -- it would break out of this, when using a new Gson as suggested by you, but that would lose all the other adapters etc. defined for the original Gson as well.